# Why passing an object automatically becomes a pass by reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference

I am trying to authenticate Admin Login in my AdminController, Here is what I have done so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdminLogin(Admin admin)
    {
        Admin newAdmin = admin;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Admin validAdmin = _iadmin.AuthenticateAdmin(admin);
            if(newAdmin.AdminName == validAdmin.AdminName)
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Valid";
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

public Admin AuthenticateAdmin(Admin admin)
    {
        int count = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AdminName", admin.AdminName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AdminPassword", admin.AdminPassword);


                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count++;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

        }
        if (count==0)
        {
            admin.AdminName = "";
            admin.AdminPassword = "";
        }
        return admin;
    }
```

The problem is: when `AuthenticateAdmin(admin)` is executed, `validAdmin` and `newAdmin` have the save values. From my understanding, `newAdmin` should have the initial parameters passed by the admin and when `AuthenticateAdmin` runs, `validAdmin` should have new values set in the authenticate method.

Why is this an automatic pass by reference?

I have looked at [someone asking the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041297/why-are-objects-automatically-passed-by-reference) before but didn't help me much.

Comment: Because classes use pass-by-reference semantics in c#.  This is part of the language.  It's unclear why that question didn't help you much, because it answers precisely what you're asking.  Please explain.

Comment: Can you share your `AuthenticateAdmin` method?

Comment: Are you really asking why C# has pass by reference semantics, or why your method doesn't work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am asking why the way i am doing it, automatically becomes a pass by reference if I haven't explicitly mentioned it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Added it, Should've added it initially. Sorry about that.

Comment: The difference between between structs and classes :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251608/are-structs-pass-by-value

Comment: @Amy It provides a detailed answer to my question but doesn't give an example. So the way I understood it, when I assign admin values to newAdmin, the newadmin shouldn't change when the authenticate is called on the admin. changes

Comment: @New_developer The *question itself* contains an example of pass-by-reference semantics.  *Your* question contains an example.  Classes are passed by reference in c# because that is how the language works.  You do not need to explicitly tell it to do so.

Comment: @New_developer If `Admin` is a class then it's a reference type and thus you update the object and return the a copy of the reference to that same object.  If it were a struct it would copy it when passed and thus you'd return a different copy.  Note that's different from how the variable is passed, which is actually by value unless the method uses the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AuthenticateAdmin` method, you're returning *a reference* to the same object you passed in.

If you want to return a *different* object, you need to do something like this:

```
return new Admin { AdminName="", Password="" };
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Thank You. This solved my problem. I have been pulling my hair trying to solve this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting confused; when you pass an object to a method, you are always passing an existing object, not creating a new object with the same state. This is why they are known as reference types.

```
var someObject = new SomeClass();
var sameObject = SomeMethod(someObject); // still the same object
bool theSame = someObject == sameObject; // true

SomeClass SomeMethod(SomeClass someObject)
{
    SomeClass insideMethod = someObject; // still the same object
    return insideMethod; // return object passed to method
}
```

By "pass by reference" you may be thinking of the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword. This does something different, it also passes the variable pointer:

```
var someObject = new SomeClass();
var sameObject = someObject; // still the same object
SomeMethod(someObject); // now a new object
bool theSame = someObject == sameObject; // false

void SomeMethod(ref SomeClass someObject)
{
    SomeClass insideMethod = someObject; // still the same object
    someObject = new SomeObject();
}
```

Comment: To be clear the first example is passing a reference type by value parameter and the second is passing a reference type by reference parameter.  You can additionally pass a value type by value parameter or pass a value type by reference parameter.  Here's a good blog that explains all of this https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: There's more background about the `ref` keyword [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), including the intricacies mentioned above.