# When do you NOT use keywords for method parameters on reference types?

Tags: c#, reference, parameter-passing, value-type

I get that you wouldnt use them if you actually want a value-type to be passed by value, but why dont we always use parameters when passing a reference type? 
Wouldnt that make it more readable since it would make it very clear whats happening in the function from just the parameters, especially when dealing with immutable objects like strings?
Or is there some downside to this approach i dont see?

EDIT: I thought passing reference types implicitly passed by reference, so I thought passing "ref ReferenceType" and "ReferenceType" did the same thing, which I now know it doesnt, thanks for making me understand. I found this linked article the most helpful in unerstanding the differences(Im quite the visual learner): http://www.leerichardson.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html

Comment: "but why dont we always use parameters when passing a reference type?" What *do* we use then?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You use method parameters when you want to pass parameters to a method. Can you please post some examples of what you're trying to describe?

Comment: I mean if i pass an instance of a class, its technically the same when i add ref, but would make it clear that this parameter needs to be read and modified in the classs, sorry i forgot to actually put keywords in the title

Comment: You should provide two sample codes to show what is actualy done and what isn't done

Comment: It might be helpful to add some examples of what you're talking about - as it is now, it's hard to understand what exactly your question is.

Comment: Adding `ref` is not the same as omitting it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790736/8126362

Comment: You have 4 cases in a sort of 2-by-2 matrix, you have passing *a* reference and passing *a* value, and then on the other axis you have passing *by* reference, and passing *by* value. In other words, you can "pass a reference by value" or "pass a reference by reference". Those two are different. The `ref` and `out` keywords are for the second case, "by reference". So it's not about clarifying intent, it's about differences in behavior.

Comment: Ah thanks, i though in case of a reference type it implicitly did the same as ref!
I knew I was missing something

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing reference types with reference parameters.

Examples of reference types are classes, arrays, and strings. When you pass a class, say, as a parameter you are really passing a pointer to the class, so the method works (via the pointer) on the original object.

If you pass, say, an `int` as a non-ref parameter it is copied. Instead, if you add a `ref`, a pointer to it is passed just as if it had been a class. Modifications to non-ref value parameters are invisible outside the called method (you operate on the copy). With ref parameters, on the other hand, you operate on the original variable.

Passing a reference type as a reference parameter gives you double indirection, which allows you to modify what the reference points to in the calling scope at the cost of additional overhead when accessing the referenced instance itself.

Comment: I understand that, my thinking is, why not use ref, in and out when passing a reference type to make it clear whats being done with it in the class, ie you see its foo(in class) so you know the values of the class are only read. im not looking to actually get functionality out of it in this im just wondering if i can use those keywords to indicate intenion without any downsides

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are referring to the `ref` keyword.

Here's two examples showing that using the keyword does make a difference.

Without `ref`:

```
void SomeMethod(SomeObject someObject)
{
    someObject = new SomeObject(); // Assignment is only local to the method scope
}

var someObject = new SomeObject();
var sameObject = someObject;
SomeMethod(someObject);
bool same = someObject == sameObject; // true
```

With `ref`:

```
void SomeMethod(ref SomeObject someObject)
{
    someObject = new SomeObject(); // Assignment affects the outer scope due to ref
}

var someObject = new SomeObject();
var sameObject = someObject;
SomeMethod(someObject);
bool same = someObject == sameObject; // false
```

Using the `ref` keyword passes the variable pointer as well as the object, so reassigning inside the method affects the variable outside the method.

As well as `ref` there is also `in` and `out`; more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters).

Comment: yeah sorry the terminology is confused me so i didnt make it quite clear, i do know what ref, in and out do, im just wondering if you pass a reference type couldnt you use ref in and out to indicate what is gonna happen to it in the class, like you see "in" and you immediately know the values will only be read, purely to make the code more easily understandable.

Comment: @LuisReich the `in` modifier, which is probably the one you would want to use 99% of the time, was only introduced in C#7.2, so enforcing the use of `in`, `out`, `ref` wouldn't be backwards compatible. Furthermore, omitting them entirely means something different altogether; you **can** assign to the parameter (which you can't with `in`), but it does not reassign the pointer that was passed in (which it does with `ref`).