# PowerShell function variable by value vs reference

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior, think it has something to do with a variable being passed as a reference vs as a value.

Is this right?

Do you know of a way to be explicit passing something as a value?

Intended behavior:

Function takes an array, returns an array of the inputted array in reverse order.

When using an array, the function modifies the array in the parent scope ($originalList).

When using an arraylist, the function does not modify the arraylist in the parent scope ($originalList).

the doco is a but unclear about how which types are passed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7

```bsh
[array]$originalList = 1..5

function wtf {
[CmdletBinding()]    
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][array]$tempList
    )

    process {
        [array]::Reverse($tempList)
        return ($tempList)
    }
}




Write-Host "  before" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host '$originalList'
Write-Host $originalList
Write-Host
Write-Host ' function returns' -ForegroundColor Cyan
wtf -tempList $originalList
Write-Host
Write-Host "  after" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host '$originalList'
Write-Host $originalList
```

**Output**

```
  before
$originalList
1 2 3 4 5

 function returns
5
4
3
2
1

  after
$originalList
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are objects automatically passed by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041297/why-are-objects-automatically-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of different behaviour is here: `[parameter(Mandatory = $true)][array]$tempList`

Try this code:

```
[Array]$ListA = 1..5
$ListB = [Array]$ListA
[Object]::ReferenceEquals($ListA, $ListB) # True

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ListA = 1..5
$ListB = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ListA
[Object]::ReferenceEquals($ListA, $ListB) # True

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ListA = 1..5
$ListB = [Array]$ListA
[Object]::ReferenceEquals($ListA, $ListB) # False. ListB is a new object COPIED from ListA and converted to Array.
```

Because you are strictly expecting `Array` type as a parameter, and you pass `ArrayList`, PowerShell *implicitly* converts your `$originalList` to a **new** object with type "Array of Objects" `Object[]` type.

So, at function start you have a reference to **COPY** of data from `ArrayList` represented as `Array`. When passing an `Array`, PowerShell sees that types match, and therefore passes reference to original `Array` object

---

Depending on your task, you can make 'Always copy' or 'Always modify' functions:

```
function wtf-AlwaysModify {
[CmdletBinding()]    
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][Object]$tempList
    )
    if ($tempList -is [Array]) { [Array]::Reverse($tempList) }
    elseif ($tempList -is [System.Collections.ArrayList]) { $tempList.Reverse() }
}

function wtf-AlwaysCopy {
[CmdletBinding()]    
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][Array]$tempList
    )
    [Array]$tempListCopy = [Array]::CreateInstance([Object], $tempList.LongLength)
    [Array]::Copy($tempList, $tempListCopy, $tempList.LongLength)
    [Array]::Reverse($tempListCopy)
    return $tempListCopy
}
```